# React Native - Android - Issue with Disabling Back Button Globally

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So, I have an issue with React Native in Android. I have the following navigator:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
        Start: { screen: Start },
        Signup: { screen: Signup },
        Login: { screen: Login },
    },{
        headerMode: "none",
        initialRouteName: "loginFlow",
    })
});
```

With this, I have 3 screens, Start, Signup and Login, with `loginFlow` being the `initialRouteName`. `Start.js` contains the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton() {
    // Logic to increment backPresses removed, opens as Alert (confirm)
    if(global.backPresses >= 2){
        BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    return true;
}

render() {
    return (
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Button full onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}>
                    <Text>{"Sign Up"}</Text>
                </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <Button full onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}>
                    <Text>{"Log In"}</Text>
                </Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
}
```

Essentially, `Start.js` acts as a hub for Signup and Login. **Most importantly** it sets the `hardwareBackPress` event listener to `return true;`, to globally disable the Android back button, unless a double-press of the back button is caught (logic removed for brevity's sake).

Pressing the back button on Start, or navigating to Signup/Login then pressing the back button does nothing, which is the expected behaviour.

This functionality all works great, until `Backhandler.exitApp()` is called, the app is closed, and then reopened. When this happens, the back button is disabled on Start, but as soon as I navigate to Signup/Login, I can press the back button and return to Start, which is **not the expected functionality.**

To summarize:

1. Open App
2. Press Back (Nothing)
3. Navigate Forward
4. Press Back (Nothing)
5. Double Press Back (Exit, on Confirm)
6. Reopen App
7. Press Back (Nothing)
8. Navigate Forward
9. Press Back (Navigates Back) **PROBLEM**

I believe this is an issue with `BackHandler.exitApp();`, as just globally disabling the back button works fine. I can't figure it out though; when reopening the app, the code appears to work, but doesn't seem to apply anymore after navigating forward. Also, I'm never removing the event listener, as illustrated by results of step 4, but something seems to be preventing it.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but you should definitely be removing that event listener before you call `.exitApp()` and in `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: Haven't tried that before `.exitApp()`, but I don't want the event listener removed in `componentWillUnmount()`, as that would disable the "global" part of this requirement.

Comment: Hmm... Unfortunately adding `BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);` prior to `BackHandler.exitApp();` doesn't change the situation. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

In your component will mount in signup you can add the event listener for backhander with exit app function. this will help it will not redirect you to start screen just close your app.

Comment: I tried this, on both Signup and Login, but all this does is fix for the first 2 screens (Start, then Signup/Login). Navigating past those screens has the same issue.

Comment: if you will call the header in the screen then the header has a back button and that button redirects you to the previous screen

Comment: I know that, but this is completely unrelated.

Comment: and by default it calls the goback function of the navigator

Comment: can you describe your issue in more detail?

Comment: Not really no, it's described pretty well... Don't worry about headers and software back buttons; that's not a part of this app.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't removeEventListener in componentWillUnmount resolve this issue?

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton() {
    // Logic to increment backPresses removed, opens as Alert (confirm)
    if(global.backPresses >= 2){
        BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Calling componentWillUnmount won't remove global listener of back button, as Start.js View will only be unmounted if user closes the app. On navigation to other View through the navigator, the component remains mounted, even if it isn't visible (at least this is the behavior in react-native-navigation).

Comment: I'll have to confirm; I'm not 100% sure if `componentWillMount()` is called following `this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")` (or `"Signup"`), but I'm don't know if that's the issue. I think that `BackHandler.exitApp();` prevents `return true;` from functioning (preventing default back logic). Away from this app at the moment, will try this and see. Thanks.